# How can I get smoother animation for sliding content with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have some content sliding here.

http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/jQuery/Slider/slider.html

The HTML structure is simple. There is an outer box with a fixed height and width with the overflow set to hidden. Then there is an inner container with the width set to the full width of the content inside of it which is a series of div elements marked with the Item class.

To slide the inner container left and right I am changing the left margin. To go left I reduce the value which becomes negative and to go back to the right I return it to zero. But I am seeing a jagged animation, even in Chrome which I expect would perform better.

My question is, would it be smoother if I used a different technique to move it back and forth? Would absolute positioning be smoother or is there something else I should consider? Are there any secrets do smooth animation that I just do not know yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Margin would cause other elements to be recalculated because an element's margin affects the position of other elements around it.

Absolute positioning (on its own zIndex) would still cause repaints of other elements, but would be less costly in terms of calculating the objects around it.

This talk gives some good insight into how the browser/dom internals work

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_6bGNZ7bA&feature=channel_page

Comment: I created an alternate version that does the animation using absolute positioning but I still see the same jagged animation.

http://www.smallsharptools.com/downloads/jQuery/Slider2/slider.html

IS there anything more I can do?

Comment: I can think of many tricks that may help/may not but if I were you, I'd probably look at how they're doing it http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding  there are so many sliders out there.

Answer (score 4):

I've had good results using the jQuery "Easing" plugin, [documentation here](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

This allows you to apply various smoothed movement such as a sine, bounce, elastic, accelerate and so on, to an html element.

It's using the same techniques you mention under the hood, but it takes care of the messy absolute/relative positioning for you.  It' also cross browser and has been optimised over new versions.

One of best benefits of using easing however, is that it can help even low framerate animations look more impressive.

Comment: I am already using that easing plugin and it does not replace the animate function, it simply assists it. It just helps by giving different waypoints in the animation. If anything it causes more math to be calculated and causes the animation to slower.

Comment: OK, sorry for wasting your time, should I delete my answer?

Comment: I personally was having problems with this and so I rewrote my script from absolute positions to relative and still no go. I ended up making everything fast (<400ms). After reading this tho I gave it a shot, and now my animation can be turned up to any speed and it still looks good with any of those easings. So, @Brennan this actually does smooth out your animations making it less jerky. Ive used this in the past, but this is for a plugin and didn't want to include a special easing, but i can just include 1 :)